# How I can show other Views if I click on the FloatingActionButton?

Tags: java, android, button, view, floating-action-button

I have a `FloatingActionButton` in my Android application. If I click on this button I want to get an `OptionMenu` with a slider and a button inside it.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

//Here I want to show a slider and a button. not a Snackbar


                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                  //      .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any xml for this option menu? Could you give more details?

Comment: Do you have any graphics of expected UI? If yes then post it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 // add this line
                 openOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by slider you mean slider Menu,

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            //        .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```